# IIS Publish Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hi I have published my application and WCF and have moved the folder to the system where i need to deploy to it. I put my both published folder in D drive and mapped them in IIS. But while accesing the application from other PC  after the login page I am getting 500 Internal server issue, my login page is direct call , rest are having ajax call. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also make sure the IIS log at **C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles** for checking error description.